# Slow INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query with InnoDB

Tags: mysql

Basically I am monitoring slowest query on a website. It turns out they are something like:

```
INSERT INTO beststat (bestid,period,rawView) VALUES ( 'idX' , 2012 , 1 ) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rawView = rawView+1
```

Basically it's a logging table. If the row is already there it updates `rawView` with a `+1`

`beststat` is `InnoDB` so I have row-level locking and consindering I do a lot of inserts-updates it should be faster than MyISAM.

Anyway that query shouldn't take so long, maybe there is something else wrong. What it could be ?

Of course I have an `Unique` `Index` on `bestid, period`

### Additional Info

This table (beststat) currently has **~1mil** record and its size is: **68MB**.  I have **4GB** RAM and `innodb buffer pool size` = **104,857,600**. Mysql: 5.1.49-3

```
CREATE TABLE `beststat` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bestid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `period` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `view` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `rawView` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `bestid` (`bestid`,`period`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2020577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

---

Notice to faster thing a litte bit i could do somethijng like:

```
UPDATE beststat SET rawView = rawView + 1 WHERE bestid = idX AND period = 2012;
if (mysql_affected_rows()==0)
  INSERT INTO beststat (bestid,period,rawView) VALUES ('idX',2012,1)
```

So most of time i would run only the first query `UPDATE`. But I would like to understand why the first, more concise, query is slow.

---

I found [this interesting article](http://www.tokutek.com/2010/07/why-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-may-be-slow-by-incurring-disk-seeks/)... still reading

Comment: Is that the only innodb table you have in the database?

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE beststat\G` and post the output in your question body

Answer (score -1):

dealing with big # of rows, i suggest to use load date infile to make query faster.
To further improve the query time, you can consider using memory table as well.